# Docker npm install angular/cli freezes and returns ECONNRESET error

Tags: angular, docker, npm-install

Recently I have cleaned docker images and rebuild a project based on angular. However I can't pass this docker command:

`RUN npm install --ignore-scripts --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli`

After ~20 mins I have this error:

[image]

(request goes via http in this error log. With default https I receive same erorr)

Also, without docker - just bare `npm install -g @angular/cli`, it takes significant amount of time to pass `https://registry.npmjs.org...`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ADD requirements.txt /
WORKDIR /shared/project/projectname

RUN    apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install software-properties-common -y \
    && apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa \
    && apt-get install python3-pip -y \
    && apt-get install git -y \
    && apt-get install curl -y \
    && apt-get install vim -y \
    && apt-get install net-tools -y \
    && pip3 install -r /requirements.txt \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN useradd -ou 0 -g 0 -m node

RUN mkdir /home/node/.npm-global

ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

USER node

RUN npm install --ignore-scripts --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli

USER root
WORKDIR /shared


EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: What's your version of npm? What's your base image? Can you show a more complete example of your Dockerfile?

Comment: Also, as by your screenshot, it says right there that it most likely is network related so make sure your build machine has proper access to the internet.

Comment: added dockerfile. My internet connection seems ok. The only issue I have is with installing angular packages via npm install @angular/cli - it takes too much time to complete. Maybe RUN command gets timeout?

Comment: Why do you depend on the ubuntu image instead of the [node:8](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) one?

Comment: And is the entire run uncached? Gut feeling tells me that a cached `apt-get update`  might be to blame. Try `docker build --no-cache .`

Comment: I have tried a simplified `Dockerfile` in order to just get the npm install to work, which worked fine for me.  https://gist.github.com/k0pernikus/31272884245a71dcf013b41cb894b4ea I highely suspect an internet connection issue on your build machine.

Comment: If its internet connection issue why do I fail on that specific RUN ?

Comment: `docker build --no-cache`  didn't helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166698/discussion-between-tomtom-and-k0pernikus).